# How to maximize $\frac 1 {PC}+\frac 1 {PB}$?

Tags: geometry

Assume $P$ is a point inside the angle $\hat A$. How to draw a line that intersects with lines $a$ and $b$ AND maximizes $\frac 1 {PC}+\frac 1 {PB}$ ?

Here is the picture:

[image: pic]

EDIT:

The point $P$ is given. the only thing changeable is the angle of the line passing the point $P$.

Comment: Well if you call the line $l$, if $A \in l$ then that quantity is $+\infty$. So if you take a sequence of points inside the angle $P_n \xrightarrow{\; n \to \infty \;} A$ (limits as in metric spaces), and $l$ all parallel to each other, you can get as high as you want

Comment: no. The position of the point is not in your hand. you can only change the angle of the line passing $P$.

Comment: Oh okay, then let me answer properly

Comment: I assume you mean $$\frac{1}{PB}+\frac{1}{PC}$$ and not $$\frac{1}{PA}+\frac{1}{PB}$$ because $PA$ is already fixed and then the answer would be the line such that $PB$ is perpendicular to $AB$ .

Comment: OMG. you are right.

Comment: $1/pc+1/pb$ maximizes then pc,pb gets minimized implying we need perpendicular distances

Comment: @ArchisWelankar What do you mean by "perpendicular distances"?

Comment: shortest distances

Comment: @ArchisWelankar   Yes but it's easy to see that $PB$ and $PC$ can't be both simultaneously perpendicular to $AB$ and $AC$

Comment: ofc so we need to minimize the distance which is far away from P

Comment: That we have to minimize $PB$ and $PC$ is obvious. the problem wants "how" ? a formula that gives the angle that minimizes the $BC$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that $AP \perp BC$.

We set $X \in AB$ such that $AC \parallel PX$, and $Y \in AP$ such that $XY \parallel BC$.

Now, we have $$\triangle AYX \sim \triangle APB$$ $$\triangle PYX \sim \triangle APC$$

This gives us $$\frac{XY}{PB}=\frac{AY}{AP}$$ $$\frac{XY}{PC}=\frac{YP}{AP}$$

Summing them, we have $$\frac{1}{PB}+\frac{1}{PC}=\frac{1}{XY}$$

We need to minimize $XY$. Since $X$ is fixed and $Y$ is on $AP$, we need $XY \perp AP$, i.e. $AP \perp BC$.

Comment: I don't understand why $$\frac{XY}{PC}=\frac{YP}{AP}$$

Comment: Similar triangles. note that $XY \parallel PC$, and $PX \parallel AC$. This gives us $\triangle PYX \sim \triangle APC$.